# dates in arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I m trying during some days to get the last and first element of an array of dates.

My xml looks like this:

```
<markers>
<marker id="1" timestamp="12/31/2012 04:07:10"/>
<marker id="2" timestamp="12/31/2012 04:07:12"/>
<marker id="3" timestamp="12/31/2012 04:07:14"/>
<marker id="4" timestamp="12/31/2012 04:15:16"/>
</markers>
```

I can get the date in the loop, but when I try to get the first and the last one, I can´t. The result is a "Undefined" message.

The code is the next one:

```
 downloadUrl("myXml.asp", function(data) {
    var xml = xmlParse(data);

    var markersPath = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");    
    var path = []; 
    for (var i = 0; i < markersPath.length; i++) {
       var a = markersPath[i].getAttribute("timestamp"); 

       var b = new Date(a[a.length-1]); //last element of array
       var c = new Date(a[0]); //first element of array
    }//finish loop
   alert(b); // the message is an Invalid date
   alert(c); // the message is an Invalid date
}); //end download url
```

If anyone can help, I would be very gratefully.

Best regards and happy new year!

Comment: If you are getting an "Invalid date" error message, that's because your `xmlParse()` function fails to find or recognise your attributes as valid dates. It has nothing to do with arrays or with the code you show. A string does not become a `Date` object magically just because it resembles a date to human eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply achieve the desired results without looping over the array:

```
var markersPath = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
var a = markersPath[0].getAttribute("timestamp");
var b = markersPath[markersPath.length - 1].getAttribute("timestamp");
```

Comment: @FranRod - If this fixed the issue, you misread the error message.